# WCF Binding SOAP 1.1 requests with both "application/xml" and "text/xml" ContentTypes

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I am attempting to replace a legacy SOAP 1.1 web service with a new WCF service.

There are many existing clients and it is not feasible to change them.

I've successfully created a service and it works most clients with one vexing exception.

Since the old service was SOAP 1.1, I tried used a basicHttpBinding, like:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Whatever" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Most of my inbound messages are like the following example, and everything works fine:

```
POST http://MySoapWebServiceUrl/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: DoSomething
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1234
Host: MySoapWebServiceUrl

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <xml:InputStuffHere />
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My issue is that a couple of callers are sending exactly the same message except with Content-Type of 'application/xml' in the headers, and receiving this error:

> Error: 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml' was not the expected type 'text/xml'.

I've tried switching to binding with `wsHttpBinding` or `webHttpBinding`.

However, I cannot find a combination of settings on either of those bindings which would allow content types of both 'application/xml' and 'text/xml' and the SOAP 1.1 style "SOAPAction" addressing in the header.

I've also tried to implement a custom Text Message Encoder, starting with Microsoft's WCF example `CustomTextMessageEncodingElement`.

However, using a custom Text Messaging encoder I can set the `MediaType` to either 'application/xml' or 'text/xml'.  But, not surprisingly, clients sending the specified Content-Type succeed but clients using the other Content-Type fail.

I've also attempted to set the `MediaType` including a wildcard like `'*/xml'`, but that simply fails for all callers.

Is there a way to create a WCF binding so the service would accept a content type of either 'application/xml' or 'text/xml'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what I was trying to do is simply impossible.

I have concluded that WCF is an inappropriate technology for implementing a backwards-compatible replacement for a legacy SOAP web service which allowed various Content-Type values in the headers.

Instead, I have implemented a custom HttpModule using System.Web.IHttpModule.

Basic implementation details follow, for anyone else who has found themselves down this rabbit hole and needs a way out.

Code:

```
public class MyCustomHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBegin;
    }

    private void OnBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication) sender;
        var context = app.Context;

        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            string soapActionHeader = context.Request.Headers["SOAPAction"];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[context.Request.InputStream.Length];
            context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

            string rawRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

            var soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();
            soapEnvelope.LoadXml(rawRequest);

            string response = DoSomeMagic(soapActionHeader, soapEnvelope);

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            context.Response.Write(response);
        }
        else
        {
            //do something else
            //returning a WSDL file for an appropriate GET request is nice
        }

        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

    private string DoSomeMagic(string soapActionHeader, XmlDocument soapEnvelope)
    {
        //magic happens here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       //nothing happens here
       //a Dispose() implementation is required by the IHttpModule interface
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="MyCustomHttpModule" type="AppropriateNamespace.MyCustomHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I too was down this hole